# Add svg-icon (arrow) in after of select

Tags: css, background, css-selectors

Hi I was styling a crossbrowser select to have the same design of my dropdowns in the browsers chrome, IE, ff and safari. This works well! I used follow code:

```css
label {
  font-family: Arial;
}

select {
  transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s;
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid $BORDER_COLOR;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 5px;

  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;

  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: radio-container;
  appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <label>City</label>
  <select>
    <option>Zurich</option>
    <option>Vienna</option>
    <option>Berlin</option>
  </select>
</body>
```

What I miss now is a arrow icon which shows, that this is a dropdown (like usual). I also would like to add my costume icon (svg). I tried it with this css:

```
background: url("arrow_down_grey.svg") no-repeat center right;
```

The arrow is at the correct position (right center) and with the correct size, but just if the width of the select is big enough. When the select is not long enough, the icon is within the text like this:

[image]

My idea was now to add it in the pseudo "after" of my select. Every tutorial that I found on the internet didn't really worked. Can someone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: How about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31531865/css-change-dropdown-arrow-to-unicode-triangle

Comment: @BigRedDog Hi and thanks for the answer. This is the solution I searched for with the after - thanks. Check the answert below from Harry. It's much easier than an after and works fine. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the `padding-right` of the element to be equal to the width of the image. If you do this, the content of the element will be cut-off before the place where the image starts (like in below snippet).

```css
label {
  font-family: Arial;
}

select {
  transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s;
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid $BORDER_COLOR;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 5px 25px 5px 5px;

  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;

  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: radio-container;
  appearance: none;
  background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGBNj.png") no-repeat center right;
  
}
```

```html
<body>
  <label>City</label>
  <select>
    <option>Zurich</option>
    <option>Vienna</option>
    <option>Berlin</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  <label>Country</label>
  <select>
    <option>United States of America</option>
    <option>India</option>
    <option>England</option>
  </select>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for your fast answer! This is much easier than an "after" and it works fine, thank you sir and have a nice day! :) You'll get the mark for correct answer. ;)