# Customized drop down in HTML

Tags: html, css

I need to create a dropdown with the attached image User Interface with the customized arrow for dropdown. I have created a sample but I kept the arrow out of the select so when clicking on the arrow drop down not expanding. can anyone give me a solution.

[image]

**CODE:**

```css
.styled_select {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.styled_select select {
  padding: 9px 32px 9px 12px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 13px;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
.styled_select:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  right: 6px;
  width: 36px;
  height: 11px;
  background: url(basics-08-128.png) no-repeat 50% 60%;
  speak: none;
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<span class="styled_select">
  <select>
    <option value="">Select One</option>
    <option value="1">Option 01</option>
    <option value="2">Option 02</option>
  </select>
 </span>
```

Please anyone give me the solution for this issue. How to add a customized arrow for the select dropdown, i tried by putting the arrow out it doesn't work properly . Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS - change dropdown arrow to unicode triangle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31531865/css-change-dropdown-arrow-to-unicode-triangle)

Comment: I need to change the arrow for the drop down. How do I do it

Comment: Did you look at the linked question?

Comment: Yes. in content how do I give the arrow which i want. please give me a sample

Comment: Are you asking how to draw a chevron? ⌄ ?

Comment: Also [What characters can be used for up/down triangle (arrow without stem) for display in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22156412/1072229)

Comment: yes I can't able to specify that

Answer (score 0):

Hi try this will sure help you:

HTML:

```
<select id="mounth" class="form-control">
    <option>Category</option>
    <option>Category1</option>
    <option>Category2</option>
    <option>Category3</option>
    <option>Category4</option>
</select>
```

USE this css:

```
/* CUSTOM-SELECT */
.select-hidden {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.select {
  color: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  width: 220px;
}
.select-styled::after {
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    border-color: #212121 transparent transparent;
    border-image: none;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 7px;
    content: "";
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 16px;
    width: 0;
}
.select-styled {
    background-color: #fff;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in 0s;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    color: #878787;
}
.select-styled:hover {
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
}
.select {
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.select {
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.select-options {
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
  display: none;
  left: 0;
  list-style: outside none none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
}
.select-options li[rel="hide"] {
  display: none;
}
.select-options li {
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 0;
  text-indent: 15px;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-in 0s;
  color:#5a5a5a;
}
.select-options {
  list-style: outside none none;
  margin:0; padding:0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    animation: 0.6s ease-out 0s normal none 1 running expand;
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    transition: none 0s ease 0s ;
    transition: transform 0.3s ease 0s;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top:none;
    box-shadow:0 1px 1px #ccc;
}
.select-styled.active::after {
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    border-color: transparent transparent #212121;
    border-image: none;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 7px;
    content: "";
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 8px;
    width: 0;
}
```

JS:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script>
    $('select').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this), numberOfOptions = $(this).children('option').length;

    $this.addClass('select-hidden'); 
    $this.wrap('<div class="select"></div>');
    $this.after('<div class="select-styled"></div>');

    var $styledSelect = $this.next('div.select-styled');
    $styledSelect.text($this.children('option').eq(0).text());

    var $list = $('<ul />', {
        'class': 'select-options'
    }).insertAfter($styledSelect);

    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfOptions; i++) {
        $('<li />', {
            text: $this.children('option').eq(i).text(),
            rel: $this.children('option').eq(i).val()
        }).appendTo($list);
    }

    var $listItems = $list.children('li');

    $styledSelect.click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $('div.select-styled.active').not(this).each(function(){
            $(this).removeClass('active').next('ul.select-options').hide();
        });
        $(this).toggleClass('active').next('ul.select-options').toggle();
    });

    $listItems.click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $styledSelect.text($(this).text()).removeClass('active');
        $this.val($(this).attr('rel'));
        $list.hide();
        //console.log($this.val());
    });

    $(document).click(function() {
        $styledSelect.removeClass('active');
        $list.hide();
    });

});

   </script>
```

Comment: Here is one more example: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/button-dropdown-select

Answer (score 0):

Use Bootstrap-select extension https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/#menu-arrow

- OR -

Use this code

```
<div class="rail-select">
  <div class="select-side">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down blue"></i>
  </div>
  <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
                            <option>1</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                            <option>3</option>
                            <option>4</option>
                        </select>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.rail-select {
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;

  select {
    border: solid 1px grey;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: gray;
    height: 42px;
    appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;

    &:focus {
      outline: none;
      box-shadow: none;
      border: solid 1px grey;
    }
  }

  .select-side {
    &:before {
      border-left: solid 1px lightgrey;
      content : "";
      position: absolute;
      left    : 0;
      bottom  : 0;
      height  : 100%;
      width   : 1px;  /* or 100px */
    }

    width: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: #F3F9FE;
    height: 100%;
    left: 120px;
    border-radius: 0px 3px 3px 0px;
    border-right: solid 1px gray;
    border-top: solid 1px gray;
    border-bottom: solid 1px gray;
    pointer-events:none;

    i {
      &.blue {
        color: #4E7AF0;
      }

      left: 30%;
      top: 12px;
    }
  }
}
```

http://codepen.io/blonfu/pen/EyyPpJ