# How to change colour of select dropdown arrow?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change the colour of select dropdown arrow using CSS. Currently, it is in black colour. I want to change it to white colour.

[image: How to change the colour of arrow from black to white.]

Can anyone have any idea to solve this issue?

html

```
    <select class="custom-select mt-1 ml-2" id="e" style="font-family:Poppins;1px solid #FFFFFF;font-size:12px;color: #000000;border-radius: 30px;width:130px;height:36px;background-color:#5A71E1;color:#FFFFFF;">
            <option value="Andhra Pradesh" selected style="color:#FFFFFF;">English</option>
            <option value="Karnataka" style="color:#FFFFFF;">Malayalam</option>
            <option value="Kerala" style="color:#FFFFFF;">Hindi</option>
            <option value="Tamil Nadu" style="color:#FFFFFF;">Telungu</option>
            <option value="Telungana" style="color:#FFFFFF;">Kannada</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: I will add the code.@Alon Eitan

Comment: I have added the code. Kindly check it.@ Alon Eitan

Comment: It is white `v` in Firefox and Google Chrome. From your screenshot I think it is in mobile screen? You are using default select box triangle symbol, I recommend use [cusom triangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31531865/css-change-dropdown-arrow-to-unicode-triangle).

Comment: Actually , it is desktop screen. I Croped the screenshot.@
vee

Comment: Refer to this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31531865/css-change-dropdown-arrow-to-unicode-triangle

Comment: Ok. I got the answer from this link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-do-i-style-a-select-dropdown-with-only-css?noredirect=1&lq=1.Thanks for your support@Ritik Banger
@vee

Comment: @AbinBenny I talk about browser **name**. Glad that problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select {
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   -moz-appearance: none;
   appearance: none;       /* Remove default arrow */
   background-image: url(...);   /* Add custom arrow */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using ***Bootstrap v4+*** because of `custom-select` is ***pre-defined*** class in bootstrap css file. So if you want to change arrow color of **SELECT** element then you need to change from `css backgound propetry` to `fill="#ffffff"` inside svg.

I hope below snippet will help you a lot.

```css
body{
  background: #5a71e1 !important;
  padding: 20px;
}


.custom-select{
  font-family: Poppins;
  border: 1px solid #FFFFFF !important;
  font-size: 12px!important;
  border-radius: 30px!important;
  width: 130px!important;
  height: 36px;
  background-color: #5A71E1!important;
  color: #FFFFFF!important;
  background: #5A71E1 url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='4' height='5' viewBox='0 0 4 5'><path fill='%23ffffff' d='M2 0L0 2h4zm0 5L0 3h4z'/></svg>") right .75rem center/8px 10px no-repeat!important;
 }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

<select class="custom-select">
  <option value="Andhra Pradesh" selected>English</option>
  <option value="Karnataka">Malayalam</option>
  <option value="Kerala">Hindi</option>
  <option value="Tamil Nadu">Telungu</option>
  <option value="Telungana">Kannada</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

I got the SVG information directly from the object and paste the information on URL part. On the fill= part you can change colors and on 1rem part you can modify the distance between the arrow and the label. The no-repeat part indicate to only print one arrow.

```
select {
    background: #404040 url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 384 512"><path fill="%23ffffff" d="M192 384c-8.188 0-16.38-3.125-22.62-9.375l-160-160c-12.5-12.5-12.5-32.75 0-45.25s32.75-12.5 45.25 0L192 306.8l137.4-137.4c12.5-12.5 32.75-12.5 45.25 0s12.5 32.75 0 45.25l-160 160C208.4 380.9 200.2 384 192 384z"/></svg>') right 1rem center/8px 10px no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Welcome! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.